# Gitlab Ngix redirect to other server/page

Tags: ubuntu, redirect, server, gitlab

I am hosting a gitlab server with the omnibus pack.
The url is something like http://myurl.com/gitlab
I need/want to add a redirect to so:

```
http:/myurl.com/jsp
```

will redirect to a tomcat server I have on the local network.

Google told me I could do this by using custom nginx strings/confs enabled and write a serverblock or something like that. (Other ideas are also welcome :) )

What would be your configuration?

Comment: How Tomcat and Gitlab are related?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a rule for `/jsp` (similar to [this article](http://webapp.org.ua/sysadmin/setting-up-nginx-ssl-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat/)) to your *existing* `server` section in the nginx configuration file:

```
    location /jsp {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout      240;
        proxy_send_timeout         240;
        proxy_read_timeout         240;
        # note, there is not SSL here! plain HTTP is used
        proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insert a reverse proxy *in front of* your Gitlab instance to ensure that your intention survives code updates. This can be NGINX, Apache, or HAProxy.